# Posts refuse to load after backgrounding on LG V30

Tags: bug, android-app

I just got an LG V30 and noticed an unfortunate bug that didn't affect my Note 4.

If you

- Open the app
- Background the app / Switch to a different app
- Sleep the phone
- Wake the phone
- Bring the app back to the foreground

Many things will refuse to load. If I try to open any questions, it opens to a blank body with "Loading question" across the top and never loads, and the "notification menu" gets stuck at the loading circle. The rep menu however loads fine.

This has been 100% reproducible so far.

The only fix I've found is to completely kill the app and reopen it.

---

App version 1.0.95

LG V30 running 7.1.2

---

---

I'm happy to say that I returned my V30 because of a [separate issue](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/189512/odd-mark-at-the-top-of-the-screen-of-my-new-lg-v30), and got a Samsung Note 8 instead. It's running 7.1.1, and the app works fine. It must be an issue with 7.1.2, or the LG V30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an update to this:

Soon after posting this originally, I traded the V30 in for a Note 8, and had the same problem. I've now been living with this annoying bug for almost half a year now, until...

About a week ago the app suddenly started behaving properly, even though the app is still at the same version as when I posted this. I updated Android to 8.0.0 a while ago, but unless I was just unobservant, that didn't fix it.

I have no clue why it started working properly, but I can now leave the app, open another app (like when a question links externally), switch back to the SE app, and it allows pages to open.

Rejoice!